# Ubuntu 18.04: Disable dnsmasq-base and enable full dnsmasq

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dnsmasq

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04, and after i configured my web server i wanted to also replace the base dnsmasq since i needed support  for wildcards. After I installed dnsmasq using this  [quide](http://blog.abushady.com/2015/01/20/routing-all-dev-domains-to-local-host.html), the dnsmasq couldn't  start because the port 53 was already used, so i tried to disable the base dnsmasq by commenting out `dns=dnsmasq` from the `etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` but there was no such line ... so now i am asking you for help on how to disable the base dnsmasq.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have `systemd-resolved` enabled as the local DNS server.

You can disable it by setting `DNSStubListener=no` in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and then restart the `systemd-resolved` service.

It will then start without binding to port 53, allowing `dnsmasq` to bind instead.

Comment: Thank you mate. But i had no i solution  so i just returned to ubuntu 16.05 in the meantime :D

Comment: Didn't work for me, I ended up using /etc/hosts to set up my dev rules, instead of good old dnsmasq... And I have something like 15 rules to add. Not a PITA in the end (I only have to do it "once") but quite sad anyway :(

Comment: When I do this, I cannot connect to any websites: DNS does not work at all. do you know how I can fix this? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: @yosi1984 Does not work in Ubuntu 18.04 with July 2018 updates. This disables internet.

Comment: Thanks man worked great on ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

As yosi1984 surmised, port 53 was being used by systemd-resolved.   His solution didn't work, but it led me to the correct question and answer:  https://askubuntu.com/a/907249/25918

Answer (score 1):

Ran across the same situation recently. For those of you who have disabled internet, it means you need to either setup the full implementation of dnsmasq to resolve internal (e.g., wildcard locals) and external domains.

Alternative approach for Ubuntu 18.04 is to ditch the full dnsmasq package in favor of the default dnsmasq-base, and strictly modify the DNS resolution via dnsmasq (base) in NetworkManager.

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029882/how-can-i-set-up-local-wildcard-127-0-0-1-domain-resolution-on-18-04?rq=1

If you have installed the dnsmasq package via apt-get, make sure you uninstall first. Don't forget to reload the NetworkManager at the end of setting the new configuration files.