# Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/dnsmasq: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, dhcp, dnsmasq

So what I did was, I installed dnsmasq using the command

```
apt-get install dnsmasq
```

Now, what happens is

```
root@kali:~# dnsmasq
bash: dnsmasq: command not found

root@kali:~# /etc/init.d/dnsmasq start
root@kali:~# 

root@kali:~# service dnsmasq start
Job for dnsmasq.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status dnsmasq.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

So, I typed

```
root@kali:~# systemctl status dnsmasq.service
● dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-10-30 01:59:14 IST; 52s ago
  Process: 6132 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --test (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Oct 30 01:59:14 kali systemd[1]: Starting dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server...
Oct 30 01:59:14 kali systemd[6132]: dnsmasq.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Oct 30 01:59:14 kali systemd[6132]: dnsmasq.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/dnsmasq: No such file or directory
Oct 30 01:59:14 kali systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Oct 30 01:59:14 kali systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 30 01:59:14 kali systemd[1]: Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
```

Please help.

Comment: Does /usr/sbin/dnsmasq exist?  If not, try to reinstall it, or erase it and install it again.  Look for the binary in the usual places, and put in a symlink to make it work, and complain to the provider.

Comment: No it doesn't exist. I tried apt-get purge dnsmasq and then, reinstall it.. Didn't help

Comment: So, the problem is that the systemd unit file has the wrong path for the executable.  Do "find / -name dnsmasq\*".  If that turns up the binary, edit the dnsmasq.service file (which that should also have found).  Then try to start it again.

Comment: If there's no binary, then the package is utterly broken, and you should switch to a different repo, set of repos, or distro to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to `apt install dnsmasq-base` and not to `apt install dnsmasq`.

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04.

See other posts on the differences between `dnsmasq-base` and `dnsmasq`, for example:

1. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq (first section, "Note that...")
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304050/how-to-avoid-conflicts-between-dnsmasq-and-systemd-resolved
3. [Ubuntu 18.04: Disable dnsmasq-base and enable full dnsmasq](https://superuser.com/questions/1318220/ubuntu-18-04-disable-dnsmasq-base-and-enable-full-dnsmasq)

Comment: I had to `apt remove dnsmasq-base` before re-installing, but that worked. Thanks :)